# how to Highlight the road 1Km Ahead and 1km back using a single coordinate

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

Let's say i have a point that exists on the road.  Now i want to highlight that road using that point for about 1-1.5 Kilometer as highlighted in image below

[image]

any solution how to do this??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. Hope it helps;

```
   public class SnapToRoad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private static final String TAG = SnapToRoad.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Reader rd = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=52.0,0&destination=52.0,0&sensor=true");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        con.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        con.connect();
        if (con.getResponseCode() == 200) {

            rd = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            final char[] buf = new char[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = rd.read(buf)) > 0) {
                sb.append(buf, 0, read);
            }
            Log.v(TAG, sb.toString());
        } 
        con.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("foo", "bar", e);
    } finally {
        if (rd != null) {
            try {
                rd.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```